# How to change FAB icon within a StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter

I started with the default Statfull Widget HomePage and a FAB.
The main widget in the page is a ListBuilder that is updated from a stream using Provider.

**When an item on the list is clicked, I need to change the icon on the FAB**.
All this works fine.

Now I wonder, If I would like to change the home page as a **StatelessWidget**. So I don't need to build the entire page just to change the icon on the FAB.

How can I update the Icon if I don't have setState() to rebuild the page?

Answer (score 0):

the best answer should be use some sort of state management, but here's a quick and easy way to achieve your goal

create a function in your parent widget

```
Function callback(){
setState((){
  //change Icon
 });
}
```

Then pass it on to your stateless widget

```
CustomFabWidget(callback)
```